# Facebook Connect API callback URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a site and I put the Facebook Connect using PHP SDK 3.

The problem is that the page where Facebook returns the results after the user authenticates and grants permission. For me after a user clicks "allow", it authenticates and then returns back to the same page (index) with a query string.

What I want is that if the user clicks "don't allow", he will be redirected to a certain page like login-fail.php, and if he grants permission he is redirected to login-success.php where his data will be processed and stored in the database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a redirect URL in case of error. The best you can do is to set a redirect URL that will be the same for success or error :

```
$args['redirect_uri'] = "http://www.yoursite.com/after-dialog.php"
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
```

If the user clicks "Don't allow", he will be redirected to the page `after-dialog.php` with the following GET parameters :

```
error = access_denied
error_reason = user_denied
error_description = The+user+denied+your+request.
```

If you really want to redirect him according the success of his login, you can track it at the top of the `after-dialog.php` file by :

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
  header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/login-failed.php");
} else {
  header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/login-success.php");
}
```

Hope that helps !

---

**EDIT:** As you pointed out (in the comments of this answer) the comments in the code of the SDK say :

```
redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
```

But the [reference of the API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) says :

> If the user presses **Don't Allow**, your app is not authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the **redirect_uri** parameter.

and :

> If the user presses **Allow**, your app is authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the **redirect_uri** parameter.

I also ran some tests and the user is always redirect to `redirect_uri`, even if he clicks "Don't allow". It must be a typo in the code comments.

Comment: I found his on line 440 in base_facebook.php:
   * The parameters:
   * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
   * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
I think it's possible to redirect:
 'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten

Comment: @med You are right ! Let me edit my answer end give you some code :)

Comment: In fact, I have run some tests and you are redirect to the `redirect_uri` even if there is an error (the user clicks "Don't allow").

Comment: @med : See my edit in my answer. It looks like you still have to redirect manually the user...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved this problem with a checking of the parameter "error_reason", when an user click in Don't Allow, the url carry this parameter. You can see it in this page:

http://aplicacionesfacebookparadummies.blogspot.com/2011/09/obtener-datos-usuario-mediante-login.html